# QListView how to set font strike out

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

It is not possible to make the text crossed out in a separate cell. It turns out only to apply to everyone. Tried changing in model methods. Also applies to everyone. I looked for an example on the Internet, but it didn't work. The bottom line is for the user to select a cell, click on the button and the text in the cell becomes checked out.

My code

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
STRIKE_ROLE = Qt.UserRole + 1
import pandas as pd

class StrikeDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        font = QFont(option.font)
        font.setStrikeOut(index.data(STRIKE_ROLE))
        option.font = font


class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
            text = index.data(Qt.EditRole) or index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
            editor.setText(text)


    # def initStyleOption(self,option,index):
    #
    #     QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.initStyleOption(option,index)
    #     option.font().setStrikeOut(True)




class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data





    def setData(self, index, value, role):

        self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
        return True

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsEditable |Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled



    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
            return str(value)



    def rename_column(self, index, new_name):
        self._data.rename(index={self._data.index[index]: new_name}, inplace=True)
        return True



    def rowCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        # section is the index of the column/row.
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return str(self._data.columns[section])

            if orientation == Qt.Vertical:
                return str(self._data.index[section])

    def add_empty_row(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        try:
            self._data = self._data.append(
                pd.DataFrame(columns=self._data.columns, data=([[0] * len(self._data.columns)]),
                             index=['Пусто']))
        except IndexError:
            self._data = self._data.append(
                pd.DataFrame(columns=self._data.columns, data=([[None] * len(self._data.columns)]),
                             index=[0]))
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        self.endResetModel()
        # self.inp_.add_delete_row.emit(self.createIndex(self._data.index[-1], 0), 'add_empty_row')

    def delete_row(self, index):


        self._data.drop(self._data.index[index.row()], inplace=True)
        # self._data.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()


class TaskModel(TableModel):

    def add_empty_row(self):
        self.beginResetModel()
        try:
            self._data = self._data.append(
                pd.DataFrame(columns=self._data.columns, data=([['Новая задача'] * len(self._data.columns)]),
                             index=[self._data.index[-1] + 1]))
        except IndexError:
            self._data = self._data.append(
                pd.DataFrame(columns=self._data.columns, data=([[None] * len(self._data.columns)]),
                             index=[0]))
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
        self.endResetModel()

    def data(self, index, role):
        value = self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()]
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(value)
        if role == STRIKE_ROLE:
            font=QFont('Calibri',13)

            return font

    def setData(self, index, value, role):

            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True



class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(586, 683)
        self.Form=Form
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QHBoxLayout(Form)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout_2")
        self.dock_task_calendar = QDockWidget(Form)
        self.dock_task_calendar.setObjectName(u"dock_task_calendar")
        self.dock_task_calendar.setFeatures(QDockWidget.DockWidgetClosable|QDockWidget.DockWidgetMovable)
        self.dockWidgetContents_task = QWidget()
        self.dockWidgetContents_task.setObjectName(u"dockWidgetContents_task")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QVBoxLayout(self.dockWidgetContents_task)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_3")
        self.scrollArea_task = QScrollArea(self.dockWidgetContents_task)
        self.scrollArea_task.setObjectName(u"scrollArea_task")
        self.scrollArea_task.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2 = QWidget()
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2.setObjectName(u"scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2")
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 548, 623))
        self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(u"gridLayout")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout_2")

        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2, 4, 0, 1, 1)

        self.tasklistView = QListView(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2)
        self.tasklistView.setObjectName(u"tasklistView")
        self.tasklistView.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.tasklistView.setDragDropOverwriteMode(True)
        self.tasklistView.setWordWrap(True)
        self.tasklistView.setItemAlignment(Qt.AlignLeading)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tasklistView, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.model=TaskModel(pd.DataFrame([],columns=['a']))
        self.delegater=MyDelegate()
        self.tasklistView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tasklistView.setItemDelegate(self.delegater)

        self.label_task = QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2)
        self.label_task.setObjectName(u"label_task")
        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.label_task.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.label_task.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.label_task.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 20))
        self.label_task.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_task, 2, 1, 1, 1)

        self.calendar = QCalendarWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2)
        self.calendar.setObjectName(u"calendar")
        sizePolicy1 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy1.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy1.setHeightForWidth(self.calendar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.calendar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy1)
        self.calendar.setMaximumSize(QSize(16777215, 400))

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.calendar, 1, 1, 1, 1)

        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.add_task = QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2)
        self.add_task.setObjectName(u"add_task")
        sizePolicy2 = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy2.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy2.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy2.setHeightForWidth(self.add_task.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.add_task.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy2)
        self.add_task.setMaximumSize(QSize(40, 40))

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.add_task)

        self.del_task = QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2)
        self.del_task.setObjectName(u"del_task")
        self.del_task.setMaximumSize(QSize(40, 40))

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.del_task)

        self.check_task = QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2)
        self.check_task.setObjectName(u"check_task")
        self.check_task.setMaximumSize(QSize(40, 40))

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.check_task)

        self.verticalSpacer = QSpacerItem(20, 40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.verticalLayout.addItem(self.verticalSpacer)


        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout, 4, 2, 1, 1)


        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout)

        self.scrollArea_task.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents_task_2)

        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.scrollArea_task)

        self.dock_task_calendar.setWidget(self.dockWidgetContents_task)

        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.dock_task_calendar)

        self.add_task.pressed.connect(self.model.add_empty_row)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.Form.show()

    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.dock_task_calendar.setWindowTitle("")
        self.label_task.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"C\u043f\u0438\u0441\u043e\u043a \u0434\u0435\u043b/\u0437\u0430\u0434\u0430\u0447", None))
        self.add_task.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
        self.del_task.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
        self.check_task.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
    # retranslateUi



if __name__ == '__main__':

        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        translator = QTranslator()
        if len(sys.argv) > 1:
            locale = sys.argv[1]
        else:
            locale = QLocale.system().name()
        translator.load('qt_%s' % locale,
                        QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
        app.installTranslator(translator)
        form=Ui_Form()
        form.setupUi(QWidget())
        app.exec_()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: From your code it is correct that it's applied to all items: the only check for the strikeout is `self.strike`, which is an attribute of the instance (aka: the model, as in *the whole model*). If you want to specify a specific data/variable/attribute (font strikeout, in this case) for a specific cell, you must use a reference. For instance, create a list that includes coordinates (in the form of a tuple of rows/column) of strikeout items.

Comment: @it uses for to do list, who is strike outed, not possible to know who will be next)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the OP has not provided an MRE then my solution will only limit the general logic which is:

- Create a new role for each item where a boolean (or any other variable) is stored if the strike is applied.
- Use a delegate to set the strike in the font.
- With the clicked signal change the value stored in the role strike for selected rows.

```py
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

STRIKE_ROLE = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1


class StrikeDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        font = QtGui.QFont(option.font)
        font.setStrikeOut(index.data(STRIKE_ROLE))
        option.font = font

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = super().createEditor(parent, option, index)
        font = QtGui.QFont(editor.font())
        font.setStrikeOut(index.data(STRIKE_ROLE))
        editor.setFont(font)
        return editor


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        vlay.addWidget(self.add_button)
        vlay.addWidget(self.remove_button)
        vlay.addWidget(self.strike_button)
        vlay.addStretch()

        hlay.addWidget(self.view)
        hlay.addLayout(vlay)

        self.add_button.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.remove_button.clicked.connect(self.remove)
        self.strike_button.clicked.connect(self.strike)

    @cached_property
    def model(self):
        return QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

    @cached_property
    def view(self):
        view = QtWidgets.QListView()
        delegate = StrikeDelegate()
        view.setItemDelegate(delegate)
        view.setModel(self.model)
        return view

    @cached_property
    def add_button(self):
        return QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add")

    @cached_property
    def remove_button(self):
        return QtWidgets.QPushButton("Remove")

    @cached_property
    def strike_button(self):
        return QtWidgets.QPushButton("Strike")

    def add(self):
        text, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(self, "Title", "Text:")
        if not ok:
            return
        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
        item.setData(True, STRIKE_ROLE)
        self.model.appendRow(item)

    def remove(self):
        rows = [index.row() for index in self.view.selectedIndexes()]
        for row in sorted(rows, reverse=True):
            self.model.takeRow(row)

    def strike(self):
        for index in self.view.selectedIndexes():
            strike = self.model.data(index, STRIKE_ROLE)
            self.model.setData(index, not strike, STRIKE_ROLE)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You answer is fast and great!But for every item every delegete - it is not many?) to many creates objects and they destroy will be in python not fast.

Comment: I'm only in a sharpening device that only uses the damn connectors using this code. As simple as possible. Otherwise, in order to make a separate cell crossed out, you need to override many methods.

Comment: i know that, you know best solution for this example.

Comment: already have a delegate to change the double click behavior. Now I need this one. How can I combine them then?

Comment: I think this is the standard implementation of Qlistwiew, because when you double-click and don't select a delegate, the text becomes empty, and when you select a delegate, the text remains the same.And new MRE

Comment: how your solution aply to a model with pandas?

Comment: The concept is this: (I brought a new MRE), there are three buttons: add a task, delete, mark completed. Completed task is marked with strikethrough text when the chek key is pressed. (I'll make it checkable). Also, a check-out task can again be marked as not completed - remove the strikeout. Plus, you need the ability to edit the task.
Now it remains to understand how to make it possible to edit the text itself and make it crossed out. (I brought a new MRE)

Comment: Im so sorry for my bad code and explanation I didn’t have time to give an example, you were ahead of me. You got it right from the very beginning. You just need to tie it together. Now the problem is in delegates. How to do editing and deletion.

Comment: @ eyllanesc      Exactly. Exactly this. Thank you so much for your energy. Thanks to you, it is possible not to abandon the idea of ​​coding._)